# Insertar valores de un Array bidimensional en tabla MySqLy si existen cambios, actualizarlos

Tags: php

Quiero hacer insertar en la tabla PRU_Nosocios con los valores de un array bidimensional que llevo desde una tabla dinámica que se encuentra en un formulario.
Los valores le llegan bien, y el array es recorrido mediante un FOREACH que realiza correctamente la inserción de cada registro en la tabla.
El problema me surge que no actualiza los registros duplicados del array que tengan como clave principal el dni_nosocio que se trate y lo que hace es crear otro registro (insert) con los datos modificados.
Dejo el código.

```js
if ( !empty($_POST["dni_nosocio"]) && is_array($_POST["dni_nosocio"])) 
               { foreach($_POST["dni_nosocio"] as $index => $nf)
                  {mysqli_query($con,
                "INSERT IGNORE INTO PRU_Nosocios 
                 (numconv,dni_socio,
                 nomape_nosocio,dni_nosocio,fechanac,dom_via,
                 dom_pobla,dom_codpost,mod_licen,uso_bus,situac)
            VALUES
                 ('".$numconv."','".$dni."',
                 '".$_POST["nomape_nosocio"][$index]. "','". $_POST["dni_nosocio"][$index]."','". $_POST["fechanac"][$index]."',
                 '". $_POST["dom_via"][$index]."','". $_POST["dom_pobla"][$index]."','". $_POST["dom_codpost"][$index]."',
                 '". $_POST["mod_licen"][$index]."','". $_POST["uso_bus_inv"][$index]."','". $_POST["situacinv"][$index]."')
            ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE                                   
                        numconv='$numconv',dni_socio='$dni',
                        nomape_nosocio='".$_POST["nomape_nosocio"][$index]. "',dni_nosocio='". $_POST["dni_nosocio"][$index]."',
                        fechanac='". $_POST["fechanac"][$index]."',dom_via='". $_POST["dom_via"][$index]."',
                        dom_pobla='". $_POST["dom_pobla"][$index]."',dom_codpost='". $_POST["dom_codpost"][$index]."',
                        mod_licen='". $_POST["mod_licen"][$index]."',uso_bus='". $_POST["uso_bus_inv"][$index]."', 
                        situac='". $_POST["situacinv"][$index]."';
                                  
                  " )
                  or die('A_A_10.2.-SE HA PRODUCIDO UN ERROR EN LA ACTUALIZACION : Inscripcion No socios' . mysqli_error($con));
```

Comment: Pero insert ignore es para evitar los errores que se produzcan al hacer el ignore.. vos queres hacer un [upsert](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

Comment: Lo he probado quitando Ignore y aún así me sigue el problema "no me actualiza".

Comment: Claro, porque tenes que cambiar la instruccion segun el link que te pase, lo hiciste?

Comment: No acabo de ver como cambiar la instrucción del ejemplo a los valores que tengo, agradecería que utilizando mi código me indicarás un poco el camino. Gracias amigo.

Comment: Cual es la clave de tu tabla? Porque en el update no deberias mandarla

Comment: La clave primaria es " Id_consulta " (autoincremental) si te refieres a ella , hay otras pero son de indice pero se mandan en el update

Comment: Si tu clave es id_consulta, ahi esta todo tu problema. esa clave no va en el insert, entonces para la base de datos no hay datos duplicados para hacer un update, todos los datos son nuevos. Creo que tenes que cambiar tu pregunta a como deberia ser tu tabla y tu instruccion sql para que esto funcione. Por favor, pone la descripcion de la tabla en la pregunta y seguro alguien va a poder ayudarte mejor.

Comment: Entiendo lo que dices, sin embargo en el insert va un campo que a su vez actúa como clave indice que es precisamente por la que los datos se pueden duplicar, me estoy refiriendo al "dni_nosocio", que representa en si mismo un valor único, es decir los dnis de cada socio que se insertaran en la tabla. Lo que quiero conseguir es que cuando se recorra el array, si existe un registro que coincida con uno o varios dni de los registrados en la tabla, actualice los datos y no los inserte de nuevo.

Comment: La mejor solución es lo que te ha sugerido @gbianchi: hacer un `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`, ahora bien, para que eso funcione tienes que tener un índice `UNIQUE` sobre la columna o columnas que determinan que un registro es duplicado o no. Si la columna `dni_nosocio` no tiene una restricción `UNIQUE` entonces tienes que hacerlo a mano: leer c/fila del array, verificar si existe y hacer el `UPDATE` y si no existe hacer el `INSERT`. Aunque en este segundo caso tendrías que plantearte agregar un índice `UNIQUE` basado en esa columna, pues en otros contextos podrían insertarse duplicados.

Comment: @A.Cedano en realidad tirarle estas cosas a la db (como te deja hacer mysql) aunque comodo para novatos, lleva a esta clase de problemas y errores. Por eso mas arriba le pedi la descripcion de las tablas ;)